# Java 8 Sort using 2 fields

Tags: java, sorting, java-8, java-stream

Based one some conditions, I have read data from MongoDB and creating a `List<Document>` with resultset.

```
List<Document> documentList = new ArrayList<Document>();
```

Sample Record Looks like:

```
documentList: [
    Document{
        { _id=5975ff00a213745b5e1a8ed9,
            u_id=,
            visblty = 1,
            c_id=5975ff00a213745b5e1a8ed8,                
            batchid=null,
            pdate=Tue Jul 11 17:52:25 IST 2017, 
            locale=en_US,
            subject = "Document2"
        }     },
    Document{
        { _id=597608aba213742554f537a6,
            u_id=,
            visblty = 1,
            c_id=597608aba213742554f537a3, 
            batchid=null,
            pdate=Fri Jul 28 01:26:22 IST 2017,
            locale=en_US,
            subject = "Document2"
        }    } 
]
```

Using this documentList, again i am filtering using some conditions and then I need to sort the filter record based on some conditions (which I will get in request).

```
List<Document> outList = documentList.stream()
                .filter(d -> d.getInteger("visblty") == 1
                && (!StringUtils.isEmpty(req.pdate())? (d.getDate(CommonConstants.PDATE).after(afterDate)): true) 
                && (!StringUtils.isEmpty(req.pdate())? (d.getDate(CommonConstants.PDATE).before(beforeDate)): true)
                .sorted().skip(4).limit()
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Not sure how to sorted (Dynamically needs to change the sorting order based on input, it looks like "`pdate by DESC`" or "`subject by ASC"`)

Like: `"order by pdate DESC" or "order by pdate ASC"" or "order by subject DESC"`

How to sort using Comparator object of Document class.

Note: I have tried couple of method which was suggested by the folks, but I didn't get any luck yet.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: `(!condition1? condition2: true)` is an obfuscated variant of `condition1 || condition2`. You are maxing that out by repeating `condition1` in two terms combined via `&&`. The entire filter predicate can be simplified to `.filter( d -> d.getInteger("visblty")==1 && (StringUtils.isEmpty(req.pdate()) || d.getDate(CommonConstants.PDATE).after(afterDate)&&d.getDate(CommonConstants.PDATE) .before(beforeDate)) )`. Though, `StringUtils.isEmpty(req.pdate())` does not depend on the actual stream element, hence, could be even evaluated before the stream operation, rather than for each element.

Comment: I see your filter lambda gotten very big. I suggest you split it in parts and use [function composition](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html#and-java.util.function.Predicate-) to add these parts together.

Comment: @MProkhorov: it’s big and redundant… I don’t know which date class it uses, but perhaps the combination of `before` and `after` could be replaced by a `between` call. Then, the code would be as simple as  `.filter(d -> d.getInteger("visblty")==1) .filter(d -> StringUtils.isEmpty(req.pdate()) || d.getDate(CommonConstants.PDATE).between(beforeDate, afterDate))`

Comment: @Holger, yes, even that is much better (after proper formatting ofc), without composing the function at all.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use group comparator and parallel stream as follows:

```
List<Document> outList = documentList.stream()
                               .filter(....)
                               .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Document::getPdate)
                                                 .thenComparing(Document::getSubject))   
                               .parallel();
```

Comment: @KayV The above example is easy to understand. But i have one clarification. What if we want to do a sorting dynamically.

Comment: @Pearl You can create custom comparator in that case. And based on some condition add the required comparator in your sorted -> comparing -> thenComparing chain

Answer (score 13):

In terms of Java code, equivalent sorting comparators look like the following:

1. `order by pdate`

   Is represented by

   ```
   Comparator.comparing(Document::getPDate)
   ```
2. `order by subject`

   Is represented by

   ```
   Comparator.comparing(Document::getSubject)
   ```
3. `order by pdate, subject`

   Is represented by:

   `Comparator.comparing(Document::getPDate).thenComparing(Document::getSubject)`

If at any point you need to have descending order, you can call `reversed()` on comparator, like this:

```
Comparator.comparing(Document::getPDate).reversed()
          .thenComparing(Comparator.comparing(Document::getSubject).reversed())
```

Note, that `thenComparing` method is overridden, providing ability to pass in:

- [a Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#thenComparing-java.util.Comparator-)
- [a Function](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#thenComparing-java.util.function.Function-)-extractor (works if whatever function extracts is-a `Comparable`)
- [a Function and a Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#thenComparing-java.util.function.Function-java.util.Comparator-) (for when extracted value is not itself a `Comparable`, so you cannot use its natural order and have to specify how it should be compared.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of `.sorted()` try using `.sorted(Comparator comparator)` method.

You can create the `Comparator` used with `.sorted(comparator)` by using `Comparator.comparing()`:

```
Comparator.comparing(Function keyExtractor)
    .reversed()
    .thenComparing(Function keyExtractor)
```

for example:

```
List<Document> outList = documentList.stream()
         // do your filtering here
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Document::getPdate).reversed()
                .thenComparing(Document::getSubject))
        .skip(4)
        .limit()
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

In this example you can use method reference `Document::getPdate` and `Document::getSubject` instead of lambda expression like `d -> d.getPdate()` and `d -> d.getSubject()`